# How would this expression be evaluated?

Tags: java, boolean-logic

Consider the following expression:

`!true || false && true || false`

This evaluates to false, but what I want to know is how java goes through the operations. I'm aware of the [order in terms of precedence](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/), where `! (not)` has the highest precedence, followed by `&& (and)` then `|| (or)`.

There are a few ways I can see it being evaluated:

- `(!true) || (false && true) || false`
- `!(true || false) && (true || false)`
- `!(true || (false && true) || false)`

Comment: The first one is correct

Comment: if you want to check how java goes though operations, convert your boolean values to function calls. then in each function set up breakpoint or log calling it, then you will see

Comment: If you understand that ! has the highest precedence, then &&, then ||, I don't see how you could possibly have come up with 2 or 3.

Comment: AS you said that ! and && has higher precedence then || then why even you consider 2? 3dr is totally different expression

Comment: The middle part is what is most confusing to me. I wasn't sure if it would evaluate the middle expression first then use it for both sides of the "or" expressions or if it would be "or and or".
Also, thanks for the tip @user902383

Comment: Nevertheless I would always use parenthesis for readability, even if the precedence comes into play.

Comment: @AlexisC. Redundant parentheses reduce readability rather than increasing it.

Comment: @AlexisC. Indeed, I would as well. I am studying for an upcoming test and the teacher likes to put tricky stuff that is obfuscated/hard to read on tests so I figured being able to understand the logic would help.

Comment: @EJP So you prefer `!true || false && true || false` than `!true || (false && true) || false` ?

Comment: @AlexisC. Certainly I do. Why don't you? It is non-redundant and sufficient. If I saw a version with redundant parentheses I would have to waste time worrying whether the programmer didn't understand operator precedence and/or hadn't expressed the intention correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You correctly pointed the operator precedence docs, and it derives from the same docs that neither 2nd, nor 3rd option can be correct. Second breaks both ! and && precedence rules, and third one breaks the ! precedence rule.

First option is closest to the way Java does it, but Java will also short-circuit && and || operators (evaluates only to the point where definitive answer can be given - that is first `true` for || and first `false` for &&). So in `false && true` it will only evaluate first condition (`false`) and skip the rest.